# how to store phone_number fields in Flask model

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

In Django I'd use PhoneNumberField like this

```
phone_number = PhoneNumberField(
    unique=True,
    blank=False,
    null=True
)
```

I need to use the phone number for logging in.

so what's the best practice in Flask (I'm new to it).

Answer (score 1):

WTForms is popularly used w/ flask. Field Enclosures allow you to handle phone numbers such as the following:

```
class TelephoneForm(Form):
    country_code = IntegerField('Country Code', [validators.required()])
    area_code    = IntegerField('Area Code/Exchange', [validators.required()])
    number       = StringField('Number')

class ContactForm(Form):
    first_name   = StringField()
    last_name    = StringField()
    mobile_phone = FormField(TelephoneForm)
    office_phone = FormField(TelephoneForm)
```

source -> https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/
control + f the page for word phone